# How to use plugins from TinyMCE in Vaadin?

Tags: tinymce, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I am using TinyMCE for Flow, since I work with Vaadin 14. I am trying to use the auto save plugin for TinyMCE. It requires this setup in a .js file:

tinymce.init({

selector: 'textarea',

plugins: 'autosave',

toolbar: 'restoredraft'

});

But it seems like there is no such javascript settings file in Tiny MCE for Flow. So is it possible to use plugins from TinyMCE in Vaadin?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using https://vaadin.com/directory/component/tinymce-for-flow you can configure it in Java like this:

```
TinyMce tinyMce = new TinyMce();
tinyMce.configurePlugin(true, Plugin.TABLE)
       .configureMenubar(true, Menubar.TABLE)
       .configureToolbar(true, Toolbar.TABLE);
```

Just look at constants ou have to use.

Comment: I use Vaadin 14 and the configurePlugin method is not available there. The setConfig(String jsonConfig) method is used instead. A string containing "autosave" is used here, containt this text and more:

+"\"plugins\": \"paste fullpage searchreplace fullscreen charmap insertdatetime lists textcolor textpattern link spellchecker autosave code help\" ,"

+"\"autosave_ask_before_unload\": \"true\" ," But the autosave plugin does not work like it should. Do we have to upgrade to a later Vaadin version for the  autosave plugin to work? Then we would be able to use the configurePlugin method.

Comment: I found this tutorial, but they use regular TinyMCE and not TinyMCE for Flow: https://trycatchdebug.net/news/1167996/tinymce-autosave-in-vaadin-14